# I/O process limit on server is getting overloaded

Tags: mysql, optimization, server, query-optimization

Recently i am facing issues with my server.

Requests are getting delayed or bounced back and possible or main cause is that
(which is being shared by Server Support team) is that **I/O limits are exceeding**.
(40K to 50K I/O operation a minute)

Possible ways to resolve this

1. To optimize the application.
2. Increase Server Resources.

I am trying both methods, have increased server resources, and working on optimizing the application.

Meanwhile have many questions and have tried to search for the answers on internet/books etc. but somehow didn't find any reliable answer.

Have few queries.

1. How are the I/O processes being calculated?

`If i am calling 5 queries from application backend one by one  does that count to total of 5 I/O operation?`

`If i am calling 2 queries but now i have combined 3 different queries into one query so how many I/O operation will be counted?  but what i have noticed is due to this total response time was increased when compared to earlier one.`

2. How should this type of situation to be tackled, as traffic will keep on increasing and sooner or later even after application is optimized I/O operation will catch up with time.
3. Looking for guidance who has worked on some sort of Social Media Architecture / Platform ON backend MySQL, server resource management.

Some of these question may seem too naive or silly to you, but since i have little experience in this i am trying to learn and trying to solve by whatever means i can.

**EDIT**
Below is the I/O log shared by server Support team
I have checked your server and currently the I/O details for your container are:

```
[code2020-07-15 11:09 | CPU: 78.42 | IOPs-Read: 57899 | IOPs-Write: 3835
2020-07-15 11:08 | CPU: 64.63 | IOPs-Read: 57880 | IOPs-Write: 3855
2020-07-15 11:07 | CPU: 76.40 | IOPs-Read: 33240 | IOPs-Write: 4575
2020-07-15 11:06 | CPU: 93.91 | IOPs-Read: 61386 | IOPs-Write: 4463
2020-07-15 11:05 | CPU: 105.35 | IOPs-Read: 50142 | IOPs-Write: 5056
2020-07-15 11:04 | CPU: 93.25 | IOPs-Read: 55701 | IOPs-Write: 4580
2020-07-15 11:03 | CPU: 98.06 | IOPs-Read: 68514 | IOPs-Write: 4789
2020-07-15 11:02 | CPU: 123.39 | IOPs-Read: 52368 | IOPs-Write: 6383
2020-07-15 11:01 | CPU: 93.82 | IOPs-Read: 46519 | IOPs-Write: 6119
2020-07-15 11:00 | CPU: 97.86 | IOPs-Read: 69654 | IOPs-Write: 6058
2020-07-15 10:59 | CPU: 106.11 | IOPs-Read: 72819 | IOPs-Write: 6142
2020-07-15 10:58 | CPU: 68.74 | IOPs-Read: 35668 | IOPs-Write: 4630
2020-07-15 10:57 | CPU: 81.57 | IOPs-Read: 41877 | IOPs-Write: 4924
2020-07-15 10:56 | CPU: 85.56 | IOPs-Read: 59275 | IOPs-Write: 4879
2020-07-15 10:55 | CPU: 78.71 | IOPs-Read: 38883 | IOPs-Write: 4176
2020-07-15 10:54 | CPU: 53.99 | IOPs-Read: 41164 | IOPs-Write: 3068
2020-07-15 10:53 | CPU: 81.39 | IOPs-Read: 51939 | IOPs-Write: 5301[/code]
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you identify the offending queries, and send them back (with response times) to the development team. They should be able to tailor the app behavior, or add appropriate indexes. Alternatively you can throw ten times as much hardware to it, but that will solve the problem only temporarily, and at great cost.

Answer (score 0):

(to long for comment)

> If i am calling 5 queries from application backend one by one  does that count to total of 5 I/O operation?

> If i am calling 2 queries but now i have combined 3 different queries into one query so how many I/O operation will be counted?  but what i have noticed is due to this total response time was increased when compared to earlier one.

You have the wrong model for how queries use I/O.

If you are selecting a single row, and you have the unique identifier for that row, it might take 1 I/O, or possibly 0.

0 IOPs -- The data is already "cached" in ram.  So there is some effort in getting the desired data, but it did not involve any I/O.

1 IOPs -- Let's say you have a huge table and you have not yet touched a particular area of the table (whatever all that means), then it might have to reach into disk to find the desired "row".  After that, it and the nearby rows, would be "cached", thereby possibly making some future queries run without any further I/O.

Lots of I/O -- Let's say you have a huge table and you have a query that needs to look at all the rows of the table.  And the table is not cached (or maybe only some of the table is cached).  Now you will have lots of I/O operations.

Those are examples of "read" IOPs.  There are also "writes" to consider.  But first, find the slow queries so we can focus on them.

The slowlog is an excellent way to identify the slowest queries. More: mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

Comment: thank you for your reply, i have looked into slow query log and optimized those queries which were listed there, and since then the slow log file is empty

Comment: i have added I/O log shared by Support Team

Comment: so how to actually solve the High I/O issue, as few of the tables have more than 1 million rows, and those tables are accessed heavily.

Comment: While trying to find a solution what i did is in the previous flow there were 5 queries which were being called in a for loop  so i reduced their queries by adding joins to 2 under that for loop, but what i noticed is because of the join queries they were taking more time to execute compared to previous flow, so what do you suggest in this kind of scenario go with previous flow or new flow or some other suggestion

Comment: @VickySalunkhe - Lower `long_query_time` to `1` (or maybe lower); there may be others to tackle.  The I/O log indicates there is more optimization work to do.  We will need specific queries and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: can i connect with you somewhere in private as the convo will eventually become long and i have lot's of stuffs to learn, can you help me out with this.

Comment: i checked the `long_query_time` it was already set to 1, so i guess for now there are no queries which are taking longer time than 1.

Comment: mysql at rjweb dot com .  `long_query_time` is a float, so you could try `0.2` for example.  (It refers to seconds of elapsed time).